# Custom Sort in XamDataGrid for multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a multiBinding which works great,

I want to be able to sort a certain column, it displays w:width, h:height
As far as I understand I need to build a custom IComparer class which will to the comparison.

Here is my XAML

```
<igWPF:UnboundField Label="Output&#10;Width/Height" Width="auto">
  <igWPF:Field.Settings>
    <igWPF:FieldSettings SortComparer="{StaticResource SortWidthHeightComparer }">
      <igWPF:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:CellValuePresenter}">
         <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:CellValuePresenter}" >
            <TextBlock Margin="3">
             <TextBlock.Text>
              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource settingsBdsToStringConverter}">
               <Binding Path="DataItem.Key"/>
               <Binding Path="DataContext.SelectedPipeMode" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type igWPF:XamDataGrid}}"/>
              </MultiBinding>
             </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
           </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
        </Style>
       </igWPF:FieldSettings.CellValuePresenterStyle>
      </igWPF:FieldSettings>
     </igWPF:Field.Settings>
   </igWPF:UnboundField>
```

Here is my multibinding converter

```
class SettingsOutputResToStringConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values[1] is Mode && values[0] is ConfigurationKey)
            {
                var pMode = (Mode)values[1];
                var key = values[0] as ConfigurationKey;
                var res = key.GetOutput(pMode);
                return String.Format("W: {0}, H: {1}", res.Width, res.Height);
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However my problem is how to I pass the multibind result into the Comparer class

```
class SortWidthHeightComparer : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

`object x` and `object y` , are always null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gilad,
I found this post:
http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/17878.aspx

It seems like a simple solution.
I'm going to try the same approach for filtering records.

Comment: I get it i just need to remove the control template

Comment: @Gilad...I also have same issue. I have UnboundFields and each have Control Template and now I want to add Custom Sort. The link says none of the solutions works. Did you actually solved the problem. if so please let us know how you did it